# How long does it take for an Office 365 app to be approved?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365

I've submitted an app for approval in the Seller Dashboard and it's currently showing:

> DRAFT STATUS: pending approval

Roughly how long will I have to keep checking this poorly-capitalised page before my app is approved?

Comment: From MSDN: "... a week at most" http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/297a8c11-3442-453d-bbf0-16c7ece1b0fe/office-store-app-validation-process-takes-unpredictable-amount-of-time?forum=appsforoffice

Comment: For us it was 2 working days from submission (rejected), then 1 working day from resubmission (approved). We only saw testers logging in on the second day of the first submission, so I'm guessing the first day it spent in the queue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This unfortunately is a how long is a piece of string question.

APPs are approved automatically and manually, and it totally depends on how many APPs are in the queue, and this is information we are not privy too I am afraid.

Source: Microsoft

Comment: :( Not even an order of magnitude? Hours, days, weeks, months?

Comment: Nope, that is the exact response I got from Microsoft when I asked directly.

Comment: That explains the capitalisation at least. ;p